# logging request and response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have to capture specific fields of each request and response and send the details to another api in asp.net core.

i created a middleware with the help of the below github link https://gist.github.com/elanderson/c50b2107de8ee2ed856353dfed9168a2
and registered it in cofigure method of startup.cs class.

my doubt is that where the code  _logger.LogInformation(await FormatRequest(context.Request)) is going to log incoming request?
how can i send the incoming request to a url from middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anywhere inside your middle ware, you are able to redirect using

```
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("http://somepath");
        });
```